# Awesome package from Careers 2.0

Tags: discussion, jobs, swag

So, I got home yesterday, and found a mysterious package waiting for me.  I opened it up to be greeted by a very fancy Careers 2.0 box, with the phrase "go forth and be awesome" on it.

Inside this box was an <strike>Stackoverflow branded portfolio</strike> ***exclusive*** Stack Overflow padfolio.  It came with a copy of my Careers 2.0 résumé, a copy of the Joel Test, and a very cool Stackoverflow pen.

I was just wanted to say thanks for this!  It's awesome!  Also, who else got one?

Here are some pictures: [plus.google.com/photos/...](https://plus.google.com/photos/105472318960952372307/albums/5740349847001514513) (excuse the quaility, don't you just love cell phone cameras :-P)

Comment: [Jacob Relkin](http://stackoverflow.com/users/220819/jacob-relkin) got something similar just a week ago: http://pic.twitter.com/i02q2gtR Are they the same package?

Comment: And who the hell would vote to close this as off topic?

Comment: @Bolt Tempted to vote to close also just to see ;) (no, I'm not!) Sweet swag, Rocket!

Comment: @bol - someone who didn't get a fancy Careers 2.0 box :P

Comment: I'm just happy to get the odd upvote here or there... but free swag?...rub it in why don't you? ;)

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: Yep, that's the same as what I got, he just used a better camera. :-P

Comment: I'd send that legal pad back and get a fresh one.

Comment: @jonsca: The fold on it was my fault `X_X`

Comment: @Lix: *giggle* teehee

Comment: @Rocket You can't be a Careers 2.0 man with a crinkled legal pad!

Comment: @jonsca: It's all good, I got another :-P

Comment: -1 Jealous. Very cool

Comment: I just filled in my address hoping I'll get one too :). Our personal information is so cheaply bought!

Comment: @vascogotlost: I think I've already sold my soul for some stickers and a t-shirt.

Comment: @MrLister: In careers, your address is part of your profile, it can be shown to certain employers.

Comment: The conditions for abc.SE swag are pretty clear: top 2 pages/1k rep on graduation. But how can one be a careers top user?

Comment: @CodeInChaos: Number of interviews? Number of job offers?  Number of jobs?  Ratio of hired/fired?

Comment: @Rocket it can't be those things, because I just got mine today! Hehe

Comment: @AndrewBarber: Sweet. :-) Also, I was just kidding about those qualifications. :-P

Comment: @AndrewBarber To what extent have you used Careers?

Comment: @TimSiteisaForum I've set up my profile, have received a couple of contacts and replied. (though one was just yesterday, so really, just one). Neither was really for a position well-suited to me, though, so it didn't go past that.

Comment: [Sounds like a ploy to get your home address...](http://i.imgur.com/4U8Jm.jpg) Woops, there goes mine!

Comment: Mine was waiting for me this afternoon. I wasn't expecting to get a bubble-wrapped black matte box in the mail. Thanks, SO!

I've filled out my Careers profile and talking to a couple of recruiters, but that's about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you Stack Overflow Careers Team, very cool, I am truly grateful!

@Rocket, correction though, you say:

> Inside this box was a Stackoverflow branded portfolio.

when the included letter states:

> "Since you're going to be going on interviews, we wanted to make sure
>   that you're well equipped so we're sending you one of our exclusive
>   Stack Overflow padfolios!"

Now, an "exclusive Stack Overflow padfolio" is something to brag about ;-)

Also, I'm embarressed to say I was not aware of [The Joel Test: 12 Steps to Better Code](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000043.html) and feel I should [read some books](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joel_Spolsky#Publications).

Here are some of the same pics:

https://plus.google.com/photos/102643749903002577693/albums/5742441911288281457

Thanks again, for the gift and encouragement. And thank you for such amazing services!

Comment: I updated the question with more glorious detail :-P

Comment: YES! I love the strikethrough :D

Answer (score 5):

Since this post seems to be about thanking SE and generally feeling superior, here ya go:

[Physics swag for top users](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1072/physics-swag-for-top-users)

A tshirt with a mexican hat on it! A retractable sharpie! A Serious Writing™ pen!

Oh, and a sticker so that your forehead can also feel superior!

---

Seriously though, this stuff is the norm on many online collaboration sites.

I already have a Google Mapmaker and a Wikipedia Ambassador tshirt. Whenever I wear these, people ask me what mapmaker is/how I got the tshirt. And I get to rant about the relevant online community :) Been able to get a few people interested as well!

So, it's good for the site. A careers-branded portfolio is even better, since it specifically targets viable users/customers of careers (these are the guys who see your portfolio, right?). Pretty awesome idea.

And of course, we get bragging rights! Win-win{*}!!

<sup>*Except for the unlucky souls who don't get  any swag</sup>

Comment: My dad used to go to trade shows, and would always come back with a bag of free swag.